# Can you have you own custom css stylesheet with semantic ui?

Tags: semantic-ui

I am on cloud 9 and I am trying to use semantic ui with my nodejs app using ejs I want to style the body tag from my own custom css but it won't work. How do I do it?

Comment: make sure your custom CSS file is loaded last

Comment: I figures it out I needed to use: 
app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: If you share your code, It may help to answer. Another thing is make sure the names of your defined classes in CSS file are not normal English words. Because semantic UI use native words in English language to define class names